# Python cached list

Tags: python, list, caching, data-structures

I have a module which supports creation of geographic objects using a company-standard interface. After these objects are created, the `update_db()` method is called, and all objects are updated into a database.

It is important to have all objects inserted in one session, in order to keep counters and statistics before updating a production database.

The problem is that sometimes there are just too many objects, and the memory gets full.

Is there a way to create a cached list in Python, in order to handle lists that does not fit into memory?

My general thought was:

```
class CachedList(object):
    def __init__(self, max_memory_size, directory)
    def get_item(index)
    def set_item(index)
    def del_item(index)
    def append(item)
```

An ordinary list would be created upon initialization. When the list's size exceeds `max_memory_size`, the list elements are pickled and stored at a file in `directory`. `get_item()`, `set_item()` and `del_item()`  would handle the data stored in memory, or 'swap' it from disk to access it.

1. Is this a good design? Are there any standard alternatives?
2. How can I force garbage collection after `pickle`-ing parts of the list?

Thanks,

Adam

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `shelve`.  Your keys are the indices to your list.

Comment: Precisely, exactly, definitely what I need. Would've given more upvotes if I could.

Answer (score 2):

I think your first question is answered.  On the second, forcing GC: use gc.collect.  http://docs.python.org/library/gc.html.